# What is the ActiveRecord structure for this SQL join?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this in my controller:

```
@report_b = Case.find_by_sql("
  SELECT Employees.name, COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM Employees INNER JOIN Cases
  WHERE Employees.id = Cases.assigned_id
  GROUP BY Employees.name
")
```

It works in sqlite3/development but not in postgresql/production.

The error is: Syntax Error with a caret under the W in WHERE.

I would like to convert this to the ActiveRecord format, and try that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `Cases.assigned_id` is the foreign key you've told Rails you're using to relate to the Employees table, all you have to do is this:

```
Employee.joins(:cases).group(:name).count
```

If `Cases.assigned_id` isn't the foreign key Rails is using, then this won't work. In that case, you could modify your SQL and switch out `WHERE` for `ON`, and Postgres will be happy:

```
@report_b = Case.find_by_sql("
  SELECT Employees.name, COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM Employees INNER JOIN Cases
  ON Employees.id = Cases.assigned_id
  GROUP BY Employees.name
")
```